# How to construct prior for two variables based on known distribution of their product?

Tags: bayesian, prior, hierarchical-bayesian

Building a hierarchical Bayes model, and I am interested in Bayesian inference of two parameters $a > 0$ and $b > 0$.

Right now I am using uninformative priors on both $a$ and $b$.

But I do have distribution on $w = ab$. How can I use this information to create an informative prior on a and b?

I am willing to make any distributional assumptions on $a$, $b$, and $w$ that are convenient for modeling purposes.  Right now I treat $w$ as normally distributed (though it too cannot technically be negative).

Edit:  The motivation is that I can acquire data where I can infer both a and b, but it is expensive and estimates are imprecise (fat posteriors).  I can also acquire different data quite easily and cheaply, where a and b are not identifiable but w =a/b is.  So I'd like to use the posterior on w to inform a prior on a and b, so when I run the expensive experiment, I know I'll get better inference on a and b.

Comment: Your problem is not very specified, so there are many possibilities. Given  $a>0$, $b>0$, $w=ab$, and your desire for "convenience", a simple possibility would be log-normal for all three. This would certainly be more appropriate than normal, for positive variables. What are your "uninformative priors"?

Comment: Log-normal is a good idea.  Right now the uninformative priors are Cauchy with a big scale parameter.  Using Stan and that's kind of the default.

Comment: You say first "I do have distribution on $w$", and then later you say "Right now I treat $w$ as normally distributed". For $w$ do you have data? or a "true" expected form?

Comment: @GeoMatt22 so I have a distribution $f_w(\mu_w, \sigma_w)$, which I assume is log normal.  So I would sample like this perhaps? 

$w \sim f_w(\mu_w, \sigma_w)$

$a \sim \text{lognormal}(\mu_a, \sigma_a)$

Accept a if $log(a) < log(w)$

$b = exp(log(w) -log(a))$

Or something like that?

Comment: For log-normal, I would just use log variables, i.e. $[\hat{w},\hat{a},\hat{b}]=\log([w,a,b])$. Then these would all be normal, and $\hat{w}=\hat{a}+\hat{b}$ ... this is why I said "for convenience, you could choose log-normal". But I am still not sure what the point of your analysis is?

Comment: The point of my analysis is that I have a complex an expensive experiment where I can infer a and b directly, but with a lot of uncertainty (represented by the scale of their posteriors).  And a simple and cheaper experiment where I can infer w with some precision.  So I'd like to do the cheap experiment first, then use the posterior on w to design a more informative prior on a and b in the second experiment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46671/discussion-between-geomatt22-and-osazuwa).

Comment: One thought is that if you know (or are willing to assume) the prior $p(a)$ and the conditional prior $p(b|a)$ for any given value of a, you would actually have a joint prior for $a$ and $b$. Then you could do an analysis, where your posterior $p(a,b|\text{data}) \propto p(a) p(b|a) p(\text{data}|w(a,b))$. Depends on this way of prior specification being possible, of course.

Comment: Following [Björn's](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/86652/bj%c3%b6rn) comment, you can draw a _posterior_ on $(a,b)$ given data providing information on $w(a,b)$, not a _prior_.